# user stories for non human actors and as non-functional requirments

Tags: actor, analysis, user-stories

I have a main application. I have two typical human actors for the main application and written many user stories. But the main application needs a crawler, a scheduler and an admin application, in order to work. Are theses considered actors? I know that they are external to my main app and that they interact directly with it to achieve a goal, but they do not provide some obvious business value for non development team stakeholders.

I also have some very important specifications regarding how bad data are handled by the system and I can't think of anyone but the main application itself as an actor to describe these scenarios.

Some of the above are described in the functional and non functional requirements but I don't know if they can be described in user stories. Is this expected?

Should I just continue with my class design diagrams and sequence diagrams and document implementation details elsewhere?

Is this gap between analysis (functional, non functional requirements, user stories, conceptual diagrams...) and design (class diagrams, sequence diagrams ...) expected in many scenarios? If yes how do you bridge it (eg developer documentation, code comments)?

User stories start to slow me down because I know how to do this and can't comply with the terminology and I can't find a real world applications case studies.

Answer (score -1):

I think user stories are slowing you down because they are difficult to master if you come from a waterfall "use case" background.

No, systems are not actors in user stories, because stories are about gaining value, and such stories have no value.

You say your system can't work without a crawler. If this is true, then you can't really have delivered anything, because a broken system has no value, clearly.

I'll assume you are working on some form of search engine. A search engine does not necessarily need an automated crawler in order to return results. It certainly needs some index.

In this case you could have one story

> As a user I want to search the site so that ...,

to build the user front end against a fixed, unchanging, minimalist index, but then you could have another story (for the crawler)

> As a user I want the search results to be fresh so that ...,

and then further stories

> as a user I want to search PDFs so that ...",

to extend the crawler.

Note that none of these stories mentions the crawler. This is by-design. Stories should not design a system, just specify its purpose. This avoids premature architecture: if you are forced to require a component only through what its purpose is, them you may well discover that you can live with a simpler solution or that you can postpone its implementation significantly.

Comment: Yes, the main app is responsible of handling data, some stats and security and the crawler fetches fresh data. So should I place the last 2 user stories you mentioned in a separate crawler application, since they provide real user value for the users of the main application?

Comment: Are you sure it provides no value? If so, you have no reason to do it.